# Appending Data in Bash Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, append, computer-science

In a bash shell script how does one append read data to a csv file?
For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter name:"
read name

exit 0
```

If I want `$name` put into a `.csv` file from this script, how can this be done?

Comment: An answer is not a comment, no matter how short.

Comment: ok fair enough, removed it. I am sure this is duplicate but couldn't find matching duplicate so left a comment.

Comment: Are you honestly asking how to append a string to end of a file?? Did you even make any attempt to search ?

Comment: It sounds like you need to start with a tutorial. Here's one: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/

Comment: 123, I've had a look and couldn't find anything. You could at least help rather than posting a spitful comment about it.
I know >> appends to files but what I know is to put $name >> file.csv and that didn't work.
Glenn Jackman, I've had a look through that but there's too much to read in the time I've got to do this. Thank you

Comment: @A.Rae Try searching `append variable to file bash`. People aren't going to just give you the answer because you can't be bothered to read examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it sounds like all you need is

```
echo ${name} >> file.csv
```

The echo statement will send the value of name to standard output, and the >> will append the standard output to the end of file.csv.

Comment: I worked this out eventually, I wasn't aware I was missing the echo part of it. Thank you very much though :)